# Mongoose How to update nested model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am creating a voting app and my app model is shown below. Whenever the user votes the value is received through `req.body.select`. At first, I run some loop to find the index of that option inside `pollsOption`(Please let me know If there are better alternatives to this approach). I use that index to access the `vote` property inside `pollsOption`. Then I store the `vote` in a variable and update it by one. I want to update the value of `vote` by new vote but this is not working due to nested mongoose model.
[image]

```
 Polls.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
        .then(poll=>{
            const pollsOption = poll.pollsOption;
            let index = null;
            let vote=null;
            for (let i=0;i<pollsOption.length;i++){
                if(pollsOption[i].option == req.body.select){
                    index=i;
                    vote=pollsOption[i].vote;
                }
            }
            vote++;
            const dynKey = `'pollsOption.${index}.vote'`;

            poll.update({
                $set:{
                    [dynKey]:vote
                }
            }).then(poll=>{
                console.log("Form is updated",poll);
            });
            res.send("Form is submitted");
        })
        .catch(e=>{
            console.log("Error",e);
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way according to my knowledge to directly find and update a value in an array, only way I know how is to pull the old value from the set and add a new value. Hope this helps

```
Polls.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.aid}, { $pull: {'pollsOption' : { 'option' :req.body.select}}}  ,function (err, _Polls) {

if(err)
{
    console.log(err);
    //handle error
}
else
{

    Polls.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.aid}, { $addToSet: {'pollsOption' : {"option" : poll.pollsOption, "vote" : "new vote"}}} , {upsert: true,  new:true},function (err, _Polls) {

        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            //handle error
        }
        else
        {
            //Do Code
        }

    });

}

});
```

Comment: No in the place of [dynKey] if I use pollsOption.0.vote it works. But something like '\' is automatically added in front of the keys. I think that might be the problem

Comment: Perhaps the initial insert might be adding a "\", you might want to check that.

Comment: Wait I must say you are wrong. My logic does work. Only problem was that I was using double string in "'pollsOption.${index}.vote"". It can be solved by removing one level of colon.